# Generate random shape polygon

Tags: random, polygon, shapes

It's possible to generate polygon with random shape, filled and with outline? Something like this:

Link to image:
https://image.ibb.co/kWAWk5/solid1.png

I mean what algorithm can be used? What programming language it uses doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a number of vertices *v* where *v* > 2,

1. Draw a straight edge *e<sub>x</sub>* between vertices *v<sub>0</sub>* and *v<sub>1</sub>*, and add it to a list of edges *e*.
2. For each of the remaining vertices *v<sub>2</sub>* through *v<sub>n-1</sub>*,

   1. Randomly select one of the edges (*e<sub>y</sub>*) from *e*.
   2. Randomly pick another point *p* that's not along *e<sub>y</sub>*.
   3. Replace *e<sub>y</sub>* with 2 new edges: 1 from *e*'s starting point to *p*, and 1 from *e*'s ending point to *p*.
3. For the final vertex *v<sub>n-1</sub>*, add an edge from it to *v<sub>0</sub>*.
4. Fill the path.